# How to decide whether to create a node or a property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm having few Nodes. lets say User 1,User 2,User 3. if i want to mention the college of users, which of the following approach gives us better performance.

```
      1: Creating College as node (or)

      2: just keeping college name as property in user node like
```

Comment: It depends on the use cases you want to support with your graph model, perhaps you can tell more about those.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would model `USER` and `COLLEGE` as entities and use relationship `STUDIED_IN` and/or `STUDIES_IN`. This would allow me to answer questions on both entities for e.g. recommending users to one another based on their affiliation to a college.

Comment: I'm also doing the same. but i'm expecting some performance metrics on the both aspects..@Bala

Answer (score 1):

In graph world use nodes to express the things in your domain and use relationships to connect them. In your case I'd model any person as a node and estables "IS_COLLEAGUE" relationships between those working together.